# Can I avoid using regular expression to find even integer values from an int array?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, search

To begin with I do not write code in [java](/questions/tagged/java) on a daily basis, though I am somewhat familar with most aspects.

I have an `integer` array with mulitple values present. I then take this array and convert to a `String` array so I can use regular expression to find all **even** values that are elements of the array.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[02468]\\b");

   int[] nums    = {1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 21, 22, 23, 33, 34, 35, 42};
   String[] vals = Arrays.toString(nums).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", "); 

   List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

   for (String s : vals) {
      if (p.matcher(s).matches()) {
        results.add(s);
      }
    }
   System.out.println(results); 
}

Output // [6, 8, 22, 34, 42]
```

This question may seem silly or irrelevant, but *is their a way to perform this without using regular expression*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_operation_expression) and rewrite that for loop to be something like this:

```
for (int i : nums) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        results.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
}
```

No need for `Pattern` or the `split`.

Answer (score 3):

If `value % 2` (value modulo 2) is 0, then it is even, otherwise it is odd (it will be 1 for positive odd numbers, -1 for negative odd numbers).

```
System.out.println(12 % 2); // prints 0
System.out.println(13 % 2); // prints 1
```

See [JLS section 15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) for specifics on the modulo (remainder) operator.

So:

```
for (int num:nums) {
    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        doEvenThing();
    else
        doOddThing();
}
```

FYI `value & 1` (bitwise AND) happens to be equivalent (if binary ones digit is 0, it's even, otherwise, it's odd) for positive numbers (for negative numbers it is 1, not -1).

Comment: You take the modulo on each value. If you took the modulo of the index then it would do that. For any number `n`, `n % 2 == 0` if it is even and `n % 2 != 0` if it is odd. It doesn't matter if the number is in an array or not. See the example I just added at the end of my answer.

Comment: Note that JasonC does bring up a good point with `%` in Java, the result of using the operator can be negative. Since we're looking for 0, it's fine here, but a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks alot, this help me bang my head on my desk for my ignorance.

Comment: If your underlying goal was to bang your head on your desk you should have said so. There are more direct solutions that do not require you to do any coding. For example, it is conceivable to construct a robot that holds your head and bangs it on a desk for you. Conversely, you could remain still, and it could bang the desk on your head.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a fact that every odd number have `1` at the end of its binary representation so it looks like `???????1` where `?` can be either `0` or `1`. Here is how you can check it with binary AND -> `&`

```
public static boolean isEven(int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 0;
}
```

Comment: This is more Perl stylish to me, I like it. =)

Comment: @hwnd Perl does have a proper modulus operator, FYI. http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perloperators.php